# Zooming animation in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to make a zooming animation for a video input.

Making a panning animation is possible with the `crop` filter with something like this:

`"crop=320:240:max(0\\,min(iw-ow\\,n)):0"`

Where the first two parameters, width and height, are fixed, and the second two parameters, accept frame number `n` or timestamp `t` as expression parameters.

But width and height are evaluated only once (and cannot use `n` or `t`), so I cannot crop a size in function of time and then apply a `scale` filter to the original size.

I know I can:

- Change the filter after pulling each frame from the buffersink (I'm not in the command line, I'm using the libraries in my software). I'm doing that already, but no for *every* frame, only by user request in an online application.
- Use `geq` filter to "apply a generic equation to each frame".

Both approaches seem expensive. Is there another filter or approach I could use?

Note that I'm using zeranoe FFMPEG libraries in Windows. I'd rather not develop my own filters or modify FFMPEG source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply a simple zoom by adding

> "zoompan=z='zoom+0.001'"

to your video filters. It will, by default, zoom in to the top left corner slowly. If you want to do something a little more advanced, you can add the x and y arguments to start getting a zoom in other directions and variable speeds. An example of

> "zoompan=z='zoom+0.001':x='if(gte(zoom,1.5),x,x+1)':y='y'"

would go to the top right and

> "zoompan=z='zoom+0.001':y='if(gte(zoom,1.5),y,y+1)':x='x'"

would go to the bottom left.

Comment: Zoompan doesn't seem to work across video frames, just on one at a time.  When I use the first example on a 10s video file it zooms in on the first frame for 10s, then zooms in at the same rate on a different frame.