# Zoom effect based on audio levels using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a zoom-in/shake effect based on how loud the audio stream's bass is.

I've realized you can use `showcqt` to get a graph of the sound, but I can't figure out how to pipe that to some zoom function to do zoom based on that.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think your first challenge here is _can you alter zoom programmatically?_ If you can‘t, that should be your first question. Also, it would be worthwhile stating a language tag for ffmpeg. Zooming exclusively via CLI interface will likely get messy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240841/zooming-animation-in-ffmpeg

Comment: @fdcpp I've found it is possible to zoom programmatically based on a stream, using the `gep` filter. Though it's pretty slow.

Comment: Speed is it’s own separate set of problems. I‘d look to make sure you understand how to control the filter and then parameterise it. Again, doing this purely via CLI sounds tedious. I would probably tackle this in processing or Max/Jitter if it were real-time. If this is non-real-time, it is likely easier to do manually in video editing software